# "Unable to obtain permission for "name of the share" | win2008r2 File Server

Tags: powershell

So a friend and i wrote a script so we could get some info about the share on our file server but i keep getting an error about the shares, I am a Domain Admin so i dont think the problem is with my permissions.

Here is the script:

```
$MyPath     = "C:\File Share Info\Shares"
$shares     = gwmi -Class win32_share -ComputerName $computer #| select -ExpandProperty Name
$AllObjects = @()

foreach ($share in $shares) {
$acl = $null
$ShareName = $share.Name
$ShareCaption = $Share.Caption
if ($ShareName -notlike "*$*"){
    $objShareSec = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting -Filter "name='$ShareName'"  
    #-ComputerName $computer
    try {
        $SD = $objShareSec.GetSecurityDescriptor().Descriptor

        foreach($ace in $SD.DACL){
            $UserName = $ace.Trustee.Name
            If ($ace.Trustee.Domain -ne $Null) {$UserName = "$($ace.Trustee.Domain)\$UserName"}
            If ($ace.Trustee.Name -eq $Null) {$UserName = $ace.Trustee.SIDString }
            [Array]$ACL = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($UserName, $ace.AccessMask, $ace.AceType)
            $Identity = $ACL[0].IdentityReference.Value

            $myObject = New-Object System.Object
            $myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ShareAccessType -Value $ACL[0].AccessControlType
            $myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Identity -Value $Identity
            $myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ShareRights -Value $ACL[0].FileSystemRights
            $myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name SharePath -Value $Share.Path
            $myObject | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ShareName -Value $Share.Name
            $myObject | select ShareName, Identity, ShareRights, SharePath, ShareAccessType | Export-Csv "$MyPath\permissions.csv" -Append -Encoding Unicode #-NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "`t"

        } 
    } 
    catch
        { Write-Host "Unable to obtain permissions for `"$ShareName`""; $share.Name | Out-File "$MyPath\Failed.txt" -Append}
}
  }
```

Comment: Please add the error message to the question too.

Comment: Instead of writing your own error message for the Catch block, use the one generated by Powershell (Write-Host $_ ) which will give you a much better idea of what's wrong.

Comment: As aside, better use `If ($ace.Trustee.Domain)` instead of `If ($ace.Trustee.Domain -ne $Null)` and `If (-not $ace.Trustee.Name)` instead of  `If ($ace.Trustee.Name -eq $Null)`. If you do want to compare against `$Null`, then put that on the Left-hand side of the equasion.

Comment: its says a "a parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Append'